# QT Creator not allowing me to save anything

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm new to QT and the IDE is driving me insane.  I've hit this problem now and It won't go away.  If I load up QT Develop and edit a file, it stars it to let me know it needs saving.  If I then try to save it it warns me that the file is read only, offering me the option of "Make Writeable" why it thinks it is read only I have no idea.  It seems writeable to me before I load up QT Develop - I am not using source control or anything else.  I rebooted my machine etc the problem still exists.  Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files you are editing are read only in the filesystem, then they will be read only in the IDE as well.

Answer (score 1):

Happened the same to me under Windows 10. I moved the project, but I left some unsaved changes in the editor, along with the autosave files. Delete the autosave files and close any files that are referencing the old path. Then you can save again without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check permissions of directory where you are saving?

If your dir is work

do - $ ls -l work
     $ ls -l work/yourfile

On Unix machines, it may be a case like you copied file from one user to another

like /home/guest to /home/workgroup

--Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 7.  Probably should have mentioned that.  When I right clicked on files they had the little shield to show that permissions were required to rename or delete the files.  No idea why that was the case.  I copied them all and deleted the originals and now I'm gold.